# How To Use Spinner(in ActionBar) To Swap Between tabs in ViewPager Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I Have 
15 ViewPager Tabs viz. SECTION 1-15.
Spinner In Action Bar With Options SECTION 1-15...
ViewPager Tabs Can Be Changed by Swiping Screen Left Or Right..
But What If I Want To Jump between The tabs using The spinner in action bar.
For Example ,
when my app starts it loads the SECTION 1,But if i want to Go to SECTION 14 directly Without swiping right again and again..How can i load the section 14 directly from the spinner??

I Have tried this but somehow i cant acheive what i want

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long arg1) {
     SpinnerNavItem selectedItem = navSpinner.get(position );
     Fragment fragment = null;
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction();
     switch (position) {
     case 0:
         fragment = new Section1();
         break;

     case 1:
         fragment =new Section2();
         break;

     case 2:
         fragment = new Section3();//goes on till Section15//
         break;

     default:
         break;
     }
     fragmentTransaction.replace (R.id.content_frame ,fragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
     return true;
```

Example Code Appreciated.
Thannks

Comment: replace any of `fragment =new Section2();` by `viewpager.setCurrentItem(int item, false);`

Comment: is the rest of the code fine?

Comment: i do not know, if you have viewpager and set its adapter then you can do so else i do not know what you have done!!

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515901/how-to-start-a-fragment-from-spinner-in-action-bar) if you can help me over here.thanks